# Reputation Mathematics

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

Oh, I know, sore subject with a lot of meta-folks.  But I don't understand the mathematics involved with the reputation summary page, and I'm not an accountant (because it seems you need to be sometimes).

I answered three questions today (at this moment), [here is the summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/719186/larstech?tab=reputation):
[image]

The problem is it isn't accurate.  The ["check checkboxes status and write..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9608047/719186) question has 4 upvotes.  It was "briefly" chosen as the accepted answer before the OP changed answers (the OP wanted to accept all three answers).

That was six hours ago.

The total for the day should be 105, 30 for the "TextureBrush", 35 for "App Settings", and 40 for "CheckBoxes".  The "Checkboxes" question was unaccepted six hours ago, but is still showing that as accepted points.

I'm fairly certain my overall reputation is accurate, but the summary is inaccurate for the day and the details that go with it are a bit jumbled.

Here is a snapshot of my rep-calc page:

[image]

Comment: I'll be honest - I'm confused there too; I have alerted the troops.

Comment: Just out of sheer curiosity, does your `/reputation` page list the same totals for today?

Comment: I think most sore points for Meta folk are the ones that begin with "Oh, I know, sore subject with a lot of meta-folks" ....

Comment: @CodyGray I added a snapshot of the rep calc.  Now I'm less certain about the overall accuracy.  Matthew, just trying to be polite.

Comment: The "checked" question had an upvote from the previous day, so the numbers are right (95 points is correct), it's just the summary showing the accepted answer and having 15 points for it is goofed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so what happened here was a deferred execution bug processing the grouping and elimination of accept/unaccept, vote/unvote code behave in an odd way, leaving the last entry in a vote/unvote chain if there were multiple inside a day.

It'll be fixed in the next build (+15 will disappear, we're already hiding the -15, +15, -15 votes before it).